# AngularJS YouTube embed issue: Blocked a frame with origin "http://www.youtube.com" from accessing a frame with origin

Tags: angularjs, youtube

[**LIVE DEMO**](http://plnkr.co/edit/jBkgcOp0jKyhX4r5pYos?p=preview)

Embedding YouTube video like this:

```
$scope.youtubeURL = '//www.youtube.com/embed/W13qDdJDHp8';
```

```
<iframe width="560" height="315" 
        ng-src="{{ youtubeURL }}" 
        frameborder="0" allowfullscreen>
</iframe>
```

throws the following error (in Chrome 28):

> Blocked a frame with origin "http://www.youtube.com" from accessing a frame with origin "http://plnkr.co". Protocols, domains, and ports must match.

I don't see the same error in Firefox 23. Is this a Chrome only issue?
What would be a proper way to solve this issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not related to AngularJS, rather a bug in Chrome itself, as you can see here:

https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=17325

You can see that there is already a fix committed for it, so let's hope for it to land in Chrome Stable soon.